# Create a blank array from a model in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

hi,

I have a working model and I want to be able to just create an array from it but with only the key names and just have them empty.

To illustrate, my model **`Client`** comes from the **`clients`** table, and for example when I do this:

`$this->Client->find( 'first' );`

I get the following array (json encoded):

```
{
    Client: {
        id: "39",
        name: "andrux",
        phone: "1234567890",
        email: "me@andrux.com",
        city_id: "2"
    },
    City: {
        id: "2",
        city_name: "andruxville"
    }
}
```

As you can see, I set this model to have a relationship with the **`City`** model, so I get both **`Client`** and **`City`** arrays as a result of my **`find`** method.

Now I need to get the same array but without values, and I just can't find an answer for this, I have tried some solutions but none have worked the way I want, for example I tried using **`array_map`** function and the **`schema`** method of the model but that just gives me the column names of the **`clients`** table, which I can set to null if I want but what about the **`City`** model?

The end result I want is the following:

```
{
    Client: {
        id: "",
        name: "",
        phone: "",
        email: "",
        city_id: ""
    },
    City: {
        id: "",
        city_name: ""
    }
}
```

Anyone knows how to accomplish this? I rather find a way of doing this the cakephp way - if there is one - but any solution that gets me to my desired result will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if its ok, you could create a custom function in your model and pass in the result to it, like:

```
//can be added to your model
function reset_values($array, $replace_with) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $arr) {
    if(is_array($arr)) $res[$key] = reset_values($arr,$replace_with);
    else $res[$key] = $replace_with;
    }
    return $res;
}
$resetedArr = reset_values($arr, null); //replace values with null
echo "<pre>"; print_r($resetedArr);
```

Comment: Thanks, Sudhir, that works, I'm just going to wait for a simpler way and if I can't get one in the next few days, I'll accept your answer, I'd just prefer not to need of an additional function in my model or controller